# How to Increase the counter for subfigures in Xepersian?

Tags: floats, captions, counters, subcaption, xepersian

I am using subcaption for using subfigure environment. In one of my figures, I have more than 26 subfigures. I tried to use the alphalph package as the simplest solution I could find:

```
\usepackage{alphalph}
\renewcommand*{\thesubfigure}{%
\alphalph{\value{subfigure}}%
}%
```

Here is my problem. My thesis is in Persian(Farsi), and I'm using the Xepersian package. After adding the above code in the preamble, all of my plots got latin caption, i.e., (a), (b), ... , (aa), etc. But they should have persian letters like (آ)، (ب)، etc. How can I achieve this? Thank you very much.

On a side note, I used a template to write my thesis, and it has a lot of code, which I don't understand. It is more than 150 pages, and I only need to fix one figure now. I'm not pro at latex. Hence, I would greatly appreciate it if someone knowledgeable provide me a simple and complete solution. Because I might not understand it if you reference to some possibly known packages and commands in Latex that might be common knowledge for you.

Comment: You might try the customizable counters in `enumitem`.

Comment: Alternatively, `babel` lets you `\babelprovide[import=fa, main, alph=alphabetic]{persian}` to redefine `\alph`.  It also supports `mapdigits` to use Persian numerals and `Alph=abjad`.

Comment: @Davislor Thank you very much for your hints. I got over it by organizing my plots more wisely, and putting a caption at the bottom of each column of subfigures, so only the last row has a shared caption with all of the plots above it. This was sufficient for my particular case. But I would try your suggestions for learning purposes later. Mercy.